# TypeScript Definition File. External Plugins

Tags: typescript

So I have an existing large definition file. Lets say it is a Tree project

```
declare module Project{

    class Tree{
       x: number;
       y: number;
    }

    module Plugins{

        class Plugin{

        }

    }

}
```

So this is in the main project d.ts file. All good. Let us say this is now read only to show it should not be edited.

But now someone external has come along and decided to write a plugin but the main definition is read only and should not be edited. For example, someone made a weapon plugin. they need project-plugin-weapon.d.ts

Part of the requirement is that this plugin adds data to the original library.  So "weapon" is being added to the Tree, which looks like this in JS:

```
Project.Tree.prototype.weapon = X
```

So project-plugin-weapon.d.ts looks like this

```
declare module Project {

    module Plugins {

       class Weapons{

       }

       module Weapons{

           class Gun{

           }

       }

    }

}
```

But how can I attach the weapon property to the existing master d.ts file?

In the project.d.ts file, the Tree class must be a class because you can instantiate it. I tried to create a ITree interface so that `class Tree implements ITree`but when I try to add to that Interface from within project-plugin-weapon.d.ts then it complains that my project.d.ts file does not implement property weapon.

```
declare module Project {

    interface IGame{

        weapon: Gun; //complaint that Project.d.ts::Game does not implement weapon

    }

    module Plugins {

       class Weapon{

       }

       module Weapon{

           class Gun{

           }

       }

    }

}
```

So how would one structure a definition file to solve this?

Note that I have seen JQuery as an example, but JQuery has no class in its definition. The Fact that Tree() needs a constructor function prevents me simply copying the JQuery-Plugin method.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just pass multiple .d.ts files to the compiler?

Comment: Hey Ameen, I would be more than happy to, but the plugin extends portions of the larger definition. If `class Gun extends Project.Something` it will require that Project.Something is re-defined in the new definition. In that case, I believe I will get a slightly different but related error because Project.Tree would be a duplicate across 2 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time looking for what I wanted but it is not possible.

1. http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/539939
2. https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397800

I have created an issue on GitHub requesting open ended classes.